# Pass array as argument in python

Tags: python

I am new to python. Now I need to declare the array of size 20 and pass the array to a function.

The function expecting the array is as:

```
function(*args)
```

The `args` is an input to the `function()`.

Can anyone help me, how to pass array in python?

Comment: From which language are you coming from? Because this is as easy as `function(array)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for Python parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)

Comment: Beware that `*args` will unpack `args`. So `function` must accept at least `len(args)` arguments.

Comment: @DisplayName: That function signature can handle an arbitrary number of arguments, so to pass it a single list / tuple / array you can unpack it in the function call. Please see my answer for a simple demo.

Answer (score 20):

When you say "array" I assume you mean a Python `list`, since that's often used in Python when an array would be used in other languages. Python actually has several array types: [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html); the popular 3rd-party module [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org) also supplies an array type.

To pass a single list (or other array-like container) to a function that's defined with a single `*args` parameter you need to use the `*` operator to unpack the list in the function call.

Here's an example that runs on Python 2 or Python 3. I've made a list of length 5 to keep the output short.

```
def function(*args):
    print(args)
    for u in args:
        print(u)

#Create a list of 5 elements
a = list(range(5))
print(a)

function(*a)
```

**output**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
0
1
2
3     
4
```

Note that when `function` prints `args` the output is shown in parentheses `()`, not brackets `[]`. That's because the brackets denote a list, the parentheses denote a tuple. The `*a` in the call to `function` unpacks the `a` list into separate arguments, but the `*arg` in the `function` definition re-packs them into a tuple.

For more info on these uses of `*` please see [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the Python tutorial. Also see [What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for Python parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters).

Comment: I should mention that `bytes` and `bytearray` are also array types, although (as the names indicate) they can only hold byte values. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview for details.

Answer (score -2):

Size doesn't matter.

Just pass `list` to function.

```
def foo(mylist):
     # do whatever you want with array here
     pass
```

You don't need [`*args`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/3990145) sequence unpacking for that purpose.

Comment: I suspect that the OP cannot change the signature of the function they're calling.

Answer (score -2):

I think that what you need is easier than expected:

```
def arrayIn(arrayFunc):
    print(arrayFunc)

arraySize = 20
mineArray = [None]*arraySize
arrayIn(mineArray)
```

Comment: I suspect that the OP cannot change the signature of the function they're calling.